# SQL 3 relationships on 1 query

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I'm trying to get 3 tables from different entities, it keeps saying me there is an error, when I use where eia.carreraHorizontal.kid = eig.carreraHorizontal.kid AND eig.carreraHorizontal.kid = hch.carreraHorizontal.kid, it return a lot of result repeated.
Here is my code:

````
        List<EvaluacionIndividualAnualYGdp> lista;
        String jpql = "select DISTINCT new es.valencia.gp.sbch.entity.EvaluacionIndividualAnualYGdp(eia, eig, hch)" 
                + " from EvaluacionIndividualAnual eia, EvaluacionIndividualGdp eig, HistoricoCarreraHorizontal hch"
                + " where eia.carreraHorizontal.kid = eig.carreraHorizontal.kid = eig.carreraHorizontal.kid"
                + " ";
                //GROUP BY eia ORDER BY eia.carreraHorizontal.empleado.apellido1 ASC, eia
        TypedQuery<EvaluacionIndividualAnualYGdp> query = em.createQuery(jpql, EvaluacionIndividualAnualYGdp.class);
        lista = query.getResultList();
        return lista;
    } ``` 

The error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: = near line 1, column 302 [select DISTINCT new es.valencia.gp.sbch.entity.EvaluacionIndividualAnualYGdp(eia, eig, hch) from es.valencia.gp.sbch.entity.EvaluacionIndividualAnual eia, es.valencia.gp.sbch.entity.EvaluacionIndividualGdp eig, es.valencia.gp.sbch.entity.HistoricoCarreraHorizontal hch where eia.carreraHorizontal.kid = eig.carreraHorizontal.kid = eig.carreraHorizontal.kid ]

But i'm getting an exception. How i can get those values? Sorry for the question but i'm new.
````

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the last eig.carreraHorizontal.kid:

```
eia.carreraHorizontal.kid = eig.carreraHorizontal.kid = eig.carreraHorizontal.kid
```

should be

```
eia.carreraHorizontal.kid = eig.carreraHorizontal.kid
```

comparing a = b = b doesn't work. Probably it should be a=b and b=c

```
    eia.carreraHorizontal.kid = eig.carreraHorizontal.kid 
and eig.carreraHorizontal.kid = hch.carreraHorizontal.kid
```

And I don't know if "new" after distinct is an error as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) a wrong syntax for

```
   where eia.carreraHorizontal.kid = eig.carreraHorizontal.kid = eig.carreraHorizontal.kid
```

Instead you should use

```
    where eia.carreraHorizontal.kid = eig.carreraHorizontal.kid 
    AND  eig.carreraHorizontal.kid =  hch.carreraHorizontal.kid
```

You could avoid old join syntax based on where and use the syntax based on explicit join

```
   select DISTINCT
   es.valencia.gp.sbch.entity.EvaluacionIndividualAnualYGdp(eia, eig, hch) 
   from EvaluacionIndividualAnual eia
   INNER JOIN EvaluacionIndividualGdp eig ON eia.carreraHorizontal.kid = eig.carreraHorizontal.kid  
   INNER JOIN HistoricoCarreraHorizontal hch  ON  eig.carreraHorizontal.kid =  hch.carreraHorizontal.kid
```

and is not clear what you mean by "new" in `new es.valencia.gp.sbch.entity.EvaluacionIndividualAnualYGdp(eia, eig, hch)` there is not a new operator in SQL.